# Strict version on go.mod

Tags: go, go-modules

My dependencies in go.mod file is always updated and i don't know why. I have go.mod like this

```
module mymodule

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.5
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.14.6
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.15
    github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig v1.4.0
    github.com/ruang-guru/rg-genproto v1.0.18
    gitlab.com/ruangguru/source/shared-lib/go v1.0.28
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200513103714-09dca8ec2884
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.29.1
)
```

when i run `go get` it always change to this. see `github.com/golang/protobuf` from 1.3.5 to 1.4.1

```
require (
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.1
    github.com/gomodule/redigo v2.0.0+incompatible
    github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.14.6
    github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.15
    github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig v1.4.0
    github.com/ruang-guru/rg-genproto v1.0.18
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1
    gitlab.com/ruangguru/source/shared-lib/go v1.0.28
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200808173500-a06252235341
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.29.1
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0 // indirect
)
```

So my question is how can we set the specific version in go.mod without altering it when we run `go get` ? I'm sorry if this question is very basic because i am still new to this go.mod thing :(

Comment: Full `go get` example, please.

Comment: Why you're using `go get`? Just `go test` and `go build` should be enough to fetch the pinned packages from go.mod

Comment: i already shared the full `go get` result above @kozmo

Comment: I thought i need to run `go get` to get the packages in modcache ? @shmsr

Comment: Don't do a plain `go get`. Versions are pinned in go.mod and updated by go get.

Comment: "I thought i need to run go get to get the packages in modcache" Why do you think that?

Comment: i see. thank you for your responses. much appreciated

Comment: Do `go build ./...`, then `go test ./...`! The `build` will fetch all the package required for building and `test` will fetch the packages required for testing if (any). So that's it. You have everything on the top-level, then `go build` then `go test` is enough.

Comment: so i just need go build to get all the dependencies to my local mod cache? @Volker

Comment: ah i see, ty for your response @shmsr

Comment: The answer you accepted is correct is some sense but but try to avoid `go get` and if possible, run `go help module-get` and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your git package has `tag` version, you can use this command:

```
go get -d -v github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.3.5
```

- `-d` means "download only", if you want a direct installation, omit this flag and the build commands below this line.
- `-v` means "be verbose".